# Nestjs: How to generate "spec.ts" files if --no-spec used to disable spec files generation

Tags: nestjs

Nestjs: How to generate "spec.ts" files if --no-spec used to disable spec files generation. I need to test the complete module but i do not have spec.ts files. Is there any mechanism to generate these files for existing modules.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to re-run the spec file generation for a file that already exists. You can create the spec file manually, or you can tell Nest to create a new file of some sort, ensure that it creates a new spec file, and delete the other file it creates with it. If you are needing the boilerplate for the spec file, it's usually something like this:

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [MyService],
    }).compile();
    service = module.get<MyService>(MyService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: there are typos like `ascyn`, `moudle` need to be correct :)

Answer (score 1):

if you use vs-code plugin [nestjs snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ashinzekene.nestjs)

use prefix : `n-test` or `n-test-service` will quickly generate template code for test